# limits and colimits under forgetful functor

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, homotopical-algebra

I'm studying limits and colimits and more precisely I'm looking at forgetful functors and I'm trying to see if they preserve limits and colimits. In order to do that I first look at terminal and initial object and check if they are preserved, if not then I can conclude, but if they are preserved I don't know what else I can check.

For specific cases I try to build a left or right adjoint, but I was wondering if there was a more universal method? Like does the fact that terminal or initial object are preserved tells us something about limits and colimits in general? Because it seems that this might be true with the examples I looked at but I don't know if this is true in general.

Comment: Don't you know any kinds of limits and colimits other than terminal and initial objects? For example, did you check if general products and coproducts are preserved?

Comment: @AlexKruckman yes I did but I was wondering if I can conclude something with those specific limits and colimits

Comment: Forgetful functor is a loose term in category theory without precise definition, which commonly arises because most familiar categories are built of sets with some structure, so you can "forget" some of it. In familiar examples they usually have left adjoints, called free functors, and therefore they preserve limits.

Comment: For the preservation of limits it is enough to have a representable functor which is less restricitve than having a left adjoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A functor preserves all small limits if and only if it preserves equalizers and all small products (i.e. products of an arbitrary set-indexed family of objects). Dually, a functor preserves all small colimits if and only if it preserves coequalizers and all small coproducts.

Just preserving the terminal object (the empty product) is not sufficient to check that a functor preserves limits.

Comment: Thanks you that helps a lot! I was just wondering if the fact that here I'm only looking at forgetful functor might make it easier to check if limits and colimits are preserved

Comment: @marilou64 Think about the forgetful functor from the more common concrete cateogories (i.e. groups, rings,...). Does it preserve colimits?